# How to serialize a derived class as its base class

Tags: .net, serialization

I have a derived class that adds only methods to a base class. How can one serialize the derived class so that it matches the serialization of the base class?
i.e. The serialized xml of the derived class should look like:

```
<BaseClass>
  ...
</BaseClass>
```

e.g.
The following will throw an `InvalidOperationException`

> The type DerivedClass was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or
>   SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

```
Class BaseClass {}

Class DerivedClass : BaseClass {}

DerivedClass derived = new DerivedClass();

StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter("output file path");
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(GetType(BaseClass));
serializer(stream, derived);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to pass GetType(DerivedClass) to the serializer constructor, it must match the type of the object you serialize.  You can use the `<XmlRoot>` attribute to rename to the root element.  This example code worked as intended:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    var obj = new DerivedClass();
    obj.Prop = 42;
    var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DerivedClass));
    var sw = new StringWriter();
    xs.Serialize(sw, obj);
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());

    var sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    var obj2 = (BaseClass)xs.Deserialize(sr);
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}

public class BaseClass {
  public int Prop { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot("BaseClass")]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass { }
```

Comment: Guys, i'm having the same problem here, but this didn't work. My Base class was created from a XSD, so i don't know what to put in the [XmlRoot]
is is the name of the class, or the name of the root element from the base class(should i specify it's namespace, etc etc?)

Comment: Is there a solution if only the base but not the derived type is known?

Answer (score 1):

You can also implement ICloneable interface for BaseClass and then do :

```
var sw = new StringWriter()

var base = (derived as BaseClass).Clone()
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BaseClass))
serializer.Serialize(sw, base)

Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString())
```

Not a perfect approche, but if your base class is simple then it should also work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but can you not just cast it ?

```
serializer(stream, (BaseClass)derived);
```

**Edit**

Also, if you want to have a single XmlSerialiser that can cope with multiple derived classes & the base class then you need to specify all of the types in the XmlSerialiser constructor.

```
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BaseClass), new Type[] {typeof(DerivedClass)});
```

Then it will happily serialize multiple types. However you will also have to use the solution mentioned above to get the output xml to match between classes.

Comment: No the same InvalidOperationException is thrown

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of googling ;) I can say that you'll need some more code and implement `IXmlSerializable` for your base class, declaring all interface methods as virtual and overriding them on your derived class. Here's a sample [topic](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/455845-issues-serializing-derived-class-its-base-using-ixmlserializable-cant-see-base) and [similar problem](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32031369/how-to-force-serialize-as.aspx) resolved by interface mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided required making changes to the originating base class to deliver the proper name. I felt that was uneeded and  will demonstrate a way to get the result on **any class** provided **without changes to source**.

---

By providing an extension method on a generic type one can provide this solution to any type as needed.

```
public static class SerializerExtensions
{
    public static string ToBaseNamedXml<T>(this T instance)
    {    
        var root = instance.GetType().BaseType.UnderlyingSystemType.Name; // Get base name.

        var jsr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( instance );               // Into JSON

        var xDoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsr, root);            // Provide base name

        return xDoc.OuterXml;                                            // Out to string
    }
}
```

The above code uses Newtonsoft JSON serializer's nuget package to serialize into JSON which gets all the properties of the derived, **but not the name of the derived** like this `{"dProp":90125,"Prop":42}`. Then we reverse the process in JSON again but provide the root name *from the derived object*. Finally we return the `XDocument`s outer xml as a string.

**Result** `<BaseClass><dProp>90125</dProp><Prop>42</Prop></BaseClass>`

---

**Test Classes** Note I added to the test derived class a new property called `dProp`

```
public class BaseClass { public int Prop { get; set; } }

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass { public int dProp { get; set; } }
```

---

**Test Usage**

```
var dc = new DerivedClass() { Prop = 42, dProp = 90125} ;

var xmlStringResult = dc.ToBaseNamedXml();
```

Comment: In fairness to *NoBugz*, I mean @Hans sorry, Newtonsoft.Json did not arrive on the scene til 2011.